# Align multiple widgets within a row

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to align two widgets within a row (a Text widget and an Ink Widget) I need the text widget to be in the center and the Ink widget on the MainAxis.end the best way I have so far is to align at the mainAxis.end and placing a large amount of left padding to then 'center' the Text is there a better way to do this

this is my code:

```
 Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("Text Here"),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 150,right: 16.0),
              child: Ink(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 79, 47),
                ),
                child: InkWell(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                    child: Icon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.book,
                      size: 40.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

[using center widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wim2.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you use a Center widget on the Text widget ? It's not what you want ?

Comment: When I use the Center widget nothing happens the text remains along the mainAxis.end with the button

Comment: Can you paste an image of your end result?. It should with the Center widget.

Comment: The Text widget is wrapped with a center and the left padding of the ink was set to 0

Comment: The problem it's not in the code your are showing. If I run your code I can see the Text is center and it does not have a green background. Maybe other widget is affecting your functionality.